# How to check if I am in admin-ajax.php?

Tags: ajax

Right now for my plugin, I am using `in_admin()` to determine if the user is in the frontend of the site or in the admin area. However, the problem occurs when plugins use `admin-ajax.php` to process ajax requests.

I need a way to register hooks and plugins only when processing `admin-ajax.php` file or in the frontend of the site. What is the best way to go about doing that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Check the constant `DOING_AJAX`. Its definition is the first working code in `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Some very weird plugins, like Jetpack, are [defining that constant in unexpected places](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/95d0f7a6210c4c570b6f8bb0fb8bf81256f47cea/modules/infinite-scroll/infinity.php#L674), so you might include a check for `is_admin()` as well.

Example:

```
if ( is_admin() && defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
{
    // do something
}
```

I have [asked for a simpler way to check this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25669) a long time ago, and this was finally implemented in 4.7.0.

So for WP 4.7 and higher you can use:

```
if ( wp_doing_ajax() )
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )` is enough by itself. The constant is only set in `admin-ajax.php` so you don't need to check for a value.

Comment: @JohnReid It is a global constant, anyone can set it to any value, including `FALSE`.

Comment: Good point. There's nowhere in the WP core that sets this value but I suppose that it doesn't mean that some rogue plugin might not set it to `false` instead. A +1 for you, sir!

Comment: It is the codex way, but in practice I saw people setting that flag in their theme, so this solution is good if you want to know if you should behave like it is ajax, but might not be best if you actually need to know if it is ajax request.

Answer (score 6):

Good news, the function is there now.

```
File: /wp-includes/load.php
1037: /**
1038:  * Determines whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.
1039:  *
1040:  * @since 4.7.0
1041:  *
1042:  * @return bool True if it's a WordPress Ajax request, false otherwise.
1043:  */
1044: function wp_doing_ajax() {
1045:   /**
1046:    * Filters whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.
1047:    *
1048:    * @since 4.7.0
1049:    *
1050:    * @param bool $wp_doing_ajax Whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.
1051:    */
1052:   return apply_filters( 'wp_doing_ajax', defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX );
1053: }
```

Just to recap, the `admin-ajax.php` defines something like this.

```
File: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
11: /**
12:  * Executing Ajax process.
13:  *
14:  * @since 2.1.0
15:  */
16: define( 'DOING_AJAX', true );
17: if ( ! defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) ) {
18:     define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
19: }
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! I missed that one in the 4.7 release notes.

Comment: Hey @TomAuger, cool. This function is a Michael Jordan of ajax. Thanks 23

Answer (score 1):

Fuxias solution returns `false` also for ajax request made from the admin panel. But these requests should return `true`, because the data you are requesting is provided for an admin view. To solve this issue you can use the following function:

```
function saveIsAdmin() {
    //Ajax request are always identified as administrative interface page
    //so let's check if we are calling the data for the frontend or backend
    if (wp_doing_ajax()) {
        $adminUrl = get_admin_url();
        //If the referer is an admin url we are requesting the data for the backend
        return (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, strlen($adminUrl)) === $adminUrl);
    }

    //No ajax request just use the normal function
    return is_admin();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DOING_AJAX` constant checks if you are in `admin-ajax.php`

```
if ( is_admin() && defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
{
    // do something
}
```