# Prefilled textarea by custom post content by default

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I want textarea to be prefilled with some custom content of custom post type. The following code works well when page loads for first time.

```
function add_post_id_origin ( $tag, $unused ) {
  if ($tag['name'] != 'msg_to_friend' )  
        return $tag;

  if($tag['name'] == 'msg_to_friend'){

       $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), array(100, 100));

        $msg .= '<p style="float:left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0;"><img src="'.$src[0].'" width="100px" height="100px" /></p>';

        $pst = get_post(get_the_ID());

        $content = $pst->post_content;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

        $msg .= '<p>' . wp_trim_words($content, 100, '...'); '</p>';

        $tag['values'] = array($msg);
        $tag['options'] = array('readonly');
    }

    return $tag;  
}  

add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'add_post_id_origin', 10, 2);
```

Problem comes when we click on submit button. It throws a warning of `Trying to get property of non-object in ...` in Ajax response. The reason behind the code is that this filter `wpcf7_form_tag` is called again when we click on submit button and `get_the_ID()` returns NULL this causes `$pst->post_content` to throws the warning.

Is there any other way to do this?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: Wrap your action in `if ( ! is_admin )` if you want to run this filter only on front-end!

Comment: you could try adding a line inside the first line of the function `if 
(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) {return;}` http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70676/how-to-check-if-i-am-in-admin-ajax