# How to test if in dashboard, bypassing Ajax quirk

Tags: ajax, front-end, dashboard, testing

As the function `is_admin()` will be fooled bay Ajax requests, what is the best what to test if we are in the dashboard? We could test the URL, spotting "wp-admin" but it doesn't look as a very elegant solution.

Comment: How about using this `$url_split = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    
    if (strtolower($url_split[1]) == "wp-admin"  && is_user_logged_in()){
         // user in dashboard, not fooled by ajax requests
    }`

Comment: If you search this site for the `DOING_AJAX`  constant, I'm sure you will find lot of info on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if I am in admin\_ajax?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70676/how-to-check-if-i-am-in-admin-ajax)

Comment: It is not sufficente to test DOING_AJAX constant, because in the dashboard I am testing this condition and there's Ajax too over there (media library for example)....